# ¿Como puedo meter varios where en un WhereHas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Esta es mi consulta

```
 $recetas = Recetas::whereHas('categorias', function ($query) {
            $query->where('nombre', 'Comida alta en Grasas')
            ;
        })->paginate(5);
```

Una receta puede coincidir con varias categorias, entonces necesito poder añadir where, pero los añado y estos no imprimen nada, alguien sabe como puedo añadir condiciones a esta consulta?

Comment: ¿Buscas evaluar múltiples veces la columna nombre? ¿es ahí donde necesitas los demás `where`?

Comment: Si, una receta puede tener varias categorias, entonces necesito que tengan que coincidir todas para que este receta se muestre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el método `whereIn` que buscará la columna tenga como valor alguno de los que tu pases en el array:

```
 $recetas = Recetas::whereHas('categorias', function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('nombre', ["categoria1", "categoria2", "categoriaN"]);
            })->paginate(5);
```

De esta forma le estariamos diciendo a la consulta: Trae las rectas que tienen categorías cuyos nombres estén contenidos dentro de los valores del array pasado.

Comment: Hay forma de hacer que sea obligado que tenga que coincidir con todas las categorias. Lo intente concatenando Where pero este no trae nada.

Comment: Si me los trae, pero me los trae aunque no coincida con todos.

Comment: Ok dame un momento

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono!